# Arduino: redefinition of a function error

Tags: c, function, arduino, redefinition

"Getting the error message:

> "error: 'int ButtonStateNext' previously declared here"   (line 7 is
>   where the issue lies)
>
> "exit status 1"
>
> "redefinition of 'int ButtonStateNext'

Whenever I try to compile my arduino program..Could someone shed some light on what exactly is going wrong? I understand that the error message is telling me that i've declared ButtonNextState previously, but I see nowhere that i've done so (atleast, intentionally?). The below is the entirety of the code (posted it all since its minimal) Thanks.

```
String ButtonState;
int Pin = 4;
unsigned long timer;
int input;

//function that is to be called in loop to service
int ButtonNextState( input ) {
//Switch statement based on state
    switch( ButtonState )
    {       
        case Idle:
            if(input == LOW)
            {
                //Record time
                timer = millis();
                //Set ButtonState to wait
                ButtonState = "Wait";
            }
            break;
        case Wait:
            if(input == HIGH)
            {
                ButtonState = "Idle";
            }
            else if(timer >= 5)
            {
                ButtonState = "Low";
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case Low:
            if(input == HIGH)
            {
                ButtonState = "Idle";
            }
            break;
    } //end of switch statement

    return 0; // By default, return 0 indicating nothing is happening    
}

void setup() {
    //Set pin as input
    input = 4;
    //Set ButtonState to Idle
    ButtonState = "Idle";
}

void loop() {
    if( ButtonNextState( digitalRead( input ) ) )
    {
        //Send serial message indicating button press
        Serial.write("Button Pressed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message says that you've already declared ButtonStateNext elsewhere in your program.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, but I already know what the error message is stating. The problem is that I don't see anywhere that i've declared ButtonStateNext, so i'm not sure why it is giving that error message. I'll edit my original post to reflect that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here

```
if( ButtonNextState( digitalRead( input ) )
```

have to be

```
if( ButtonNextState( digitalRead( input ) ) )
```

And

```
int ButtonNextState( input )
```

should be at least

```
int ButtonNextState( int input )
```

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed it in my code and up above - still getting the same error message though :\ but at least that's one problem caught! :)

Comment: @ LPs that fixed it! Thanks! :P Maybe I need to not code at 2AM so I don't miss the little details in the future. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem without having any errors in my code.  I thought I would share in case it is of any use to someone looking here later.

I had mistakenly thought that I could have two .ino files in a folder, and the compiler would only look at the file with the same name as the folder.  This is not the case, and the compiler looks at all .ino files in a folder.  The redefinition error came because both files shared the same variables.

Hope this helps someone else looking for a similar problem in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the file to a different place and see if the error persists. If the file is located on the cloud I experienced the above problems with the compiler.